# What are the differences between javascript and PCRE regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, pcre

It should be a simple question: What are the differences between the "Perl-compatible regular expressions" (PCRE), supported by many languages, and Javascript regular expressions?

Sites like [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com) offer a choice between the two, but I'm not sure what the differences are. A quick google produced no results, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2227057/699305) looks like it should be a duplicate but is actually about matching email addresses-- no help at all, except to confirm that there *are* differences.

I'd be happy with a reference to a site that documents the peculiarities or limitations of multiple regexp implementations, as long as these two are included.

Comment: And if you like wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines#Language_features

Comment: Thank you all, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that PCRE and Perl regexes are not the same thing. Take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html and choose PCRE/Javascript to compare the two in great detail.

Comment: Warning: The duplicate-making question that "already has an answer" was asked and answered in 2010... I wouldn't take those answers too seriously. The link posted above by @TimPietzcker seems to be maintained, though. (At least, the page was recently updated.)